# Passar id para chamar modal

Tags: php

Tenho um array de uma tabela chamada devolucoes que utilizo pra montar um dataTable, e queria chamar um modal na coluna descrição, só que até aí tudo bem, só que ele carrega o modal vazio pois não estou passando o id na frente de #myEditar_ e não sei como faz isso, eu comentei no código essa parte linha 9.

se eu conseguisse passar o id do 1º array acredito que daria certo.

array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0),

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0),
    array( 'db' => 'empresa', 'dt' => 1),
    array( 'db' => 'ar',  'dt' => 2),
    array( 'db' => 'nf',   'dt' => 3),
    array( 'db' => 'tp', 'dt' => 4),
    array( 'db' => 'descricao', 'dt' => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d,$row ){
            return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditar_////PASSAR O ID AQUI////"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>'.substr (($d), 0, 40);
        }
        ),
    array( 'db' => 'status', 'dt' => 6,
        'formatter' => function( $d,$row ){
            return $d == 1 ? 'RELACIONADO' : '<font color="red">EM ABERTO</font>';
        }         

        ),


    array( 'db' => 'created','dt' => 7,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'd-m-Y - H:i:s', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array( 'db' => 'modified','dt' => 8,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'd-m-Y - H:i:s', strtotime($d));
        }
    )       

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar o primeiro array em uma variável separada e depois concatenar a string dessa maneira:

```
$primeiroArray = array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0);
$columns = array(
    $primeiroArray,
    array( 'db' => 'empresa', 'dt' => 1),
    array( 'db' => 'ar',  'dt' => 2),
    array( 'db' => 'nf',   'dt' => 3),
    array( 'db' => 'tp', 'dt' => 4),
    array( 'db' => 'descricao', 'dt' => 5,
      'formatter' => function( $d,$row ){
          return '
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditar_"'. $primeiroArray['dt'] .'">
              <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
           </button>'.substr (($d), 0, 40);
        }
    )
);
```